# How to increase the timeout for an axios request?

Tags: javascript, axios

I'm relatively new to JavaScript/TypeScript (still learning), and I've been trying to make requests using fetch and axios, but I'm experiencing network connection issues. The error I'm getting is:

```
cause: AggregateError
      at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1102:18)
      at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1161:5)
      at Timeout.internalConnectMultipleTimeout (node:net:1644:3)
      at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:575:11)
      at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7) {
    code: 'ENETUNREACH',
    [errors]: [
      Error: connect ENETUNREACH 2001:67c:4e8:f004::9:443 - Local (undefined:undefined)
          at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1160:40)
          at Timeout.internalConnectMultipleTimeout (node:net:1644:3)
          at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:575:11)
          at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7) {
        errno: -101,
        code: 'ENETUNREACH',
        syscall: 'connect',
        address: '2001:67c:4e8:f004::9',
        port: 443
      }
    ]
  }
}

Node.js v20.3.1
```

I consider the code unnecessary, just use an `axios({"url": "https://example.com"})`.

The network is quite slow and unstable, but I do have internet access. The requests work fine with other utilities like curl or [requests](https://pypi.org/project/requests/) in Python (on the first try with both), so it rules out any problems with my computer or network configuration.

Both fetch and axios actually work, but I'm forced to constantly retry (up to 200 times) until it decides to work. I've tried passing `{ timeout: 0 }` and `{ timeout: 5000 }` to the axios constructor, but with no success.

I have also tried this, but nothing seems to work:

```
const source = CancelToken.source();
const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
  source.cancel();
}, 10000);

axios.get(ip + '/config', {cancelToken: source.token}).then((result) => {
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  // ...
});
```

```
axios.get('/foo/bar', {
   signal: AbortSignal.timeout(5000) //Aborts request after 5 seconds
}).then(function(response) {
   // ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `timeout` property as one of the config options that you can pass to `axios`.

https://axios-http.com/docs/req_config

You can also change the its default value instead of using the `timeout` property each time:

```
const instance = axios.create();
instance.defaults.timeout = 2500;
```

https://axios-http.com/docs/config_defaults

Comment: I have the same problem, even passing the URL to axios.create().